# Causes of SQLite General error: 17 database schema has changed

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Why does declaring the prepared statement `$stmt2` before `VACUUM backup` cause the `General error: 17 database schema has changed` error?

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);


$db = new \PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."/../db/datalogger.db");
$db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

print_r($db->query('SELECT version, polltimeDestination FROM config WHERE bogus=0')->fetch());

$stmt1=$db->prepare('UPDATE config SET polltimeDestination=? WHERE bogus=0');
$stmt1->execute([300]);

$db->exec('DELETE FROM backup');
$stmt2=$db->prepare('UPDATE config SET version=? WHERE bogus=0');
$db->exec('VACUUM backup');

//$stmt2=$db->prepare('UPDATE config SET version=? WHERE bogus=0');
$stmt2->execute([8]);
```

OUTPUT:

```
stdClass Object ( [version] => 8 [polltimeDestination] => 300 ) 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 17 database schema has changed' in /var/www/html/test2.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/test2.php(26): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/test2.php on line 26
```

Comment: I assume it's an academic question without any practical application?

Comment: @YourCommonSense  While not shown, the real application is a service that runs continuously, and I felt it more appropriate if I just assign the prepared statement once.  The code I posted is just the bare minimum code to create the error.  After discovering the error, it became a little academic, and I just wish to better understand what is happening.

Comment: Makes sense. Well I am not a pro in the prepared statements' internals, but I think that the error message says it all: looks like that vacuum is considered a schema changer and a prepared statement, by its nature, is tightly coupled to the schema, running a query by half. So yes, the obvious workaround is to prepare every time. It shouldn't be a big deal

Comment: @YourCommonSense  Often when using a loop, it is very common to first create the prepared statement and then execute it multiple times in the loop.  Are there other "gotchas" other than using vacuum that one must be aware of?

Comment: Any schema changers like adding or dropping tables or columns, I'd say.

Comment: @YourCommonSense.  Okay, will do.  What was even more surprising was I vacuumed another table.  Guess when any table is vacuumed, the entire database schema is modified.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per YourCommonSense's comments...

Any schema changers like adding or dropping tables or columns will obviously result in a schema change.  Using vacuum also results in a schema change.  Attempting to execute a prepared statement defined before the schema change will result in a `SQLite General error: 17 database schema has changed` error.